# Get view function from request uri?

Tags: django

Given a uri like `/home/` I want to find the view function that this corresponds to, preferably in a form like `app.views.home` or just `<app_label>.<view_func>`. Is there a function that will give me this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the [resolve](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) method provided by django to get the function. You can use the `__module__` attribute of the function returned to get the app label. This will return a string like `project.app.views`. So something like this:

```
from django.urls import resolve

myfunc, myargs, mykwargs = resolve("/hello_world/")
mymodule = myfunc.__module__
```

In case one needs the class of the view since a class based view is being used one can access the `view_class` of the returned function:

```
view_class = myfunc.view_class
```

Answer (score 7):

From Django 2.0 onward `django.core.urlresolvers` module has been moved to `django.urls`.

You will need to do this:

```py
from django.urls import resolve

myfunc, myargs, mykwargs = resolve("/hello_world/")
mymodule = myfunc.__module__
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Django 1.3 (March 2011) the `resolve` function in the `urlresolvers` module returns a `ResolverMatch` object. Which provides access to all attributes of the resolved URL match, including the view callable path.

```python
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
>>> match = resolve('/')
>>> match.func
<function apps.core.views.HomeView>
>>> match._func_path
'apps.core.views.HomeView'
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Generate a text file with all URLs with corresponding view functions**

`./manage.py show_urls --format pretty-json --settings=<path-to-settings> > urls.txt`

**example**
`./manage.py show_urls --format pretty-json --settings=settings2.testing > urls.txt`

**2. Look for your URL in the output file** `urls.txt`

```
    {
        "url": "/v3/affiliate/commission/",
        "module": "api.views.affiliate.CommissionView",
        "name": "affiliate-commission",
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

All the others focus on just the module or string representation of the view. However, if you want to directly access the view object for some reason, this could be handy

```
resolve('the_path/').func.cls
```

This gives the view object itself, this works on class based view, I haven't tested it on a function based view though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [KillianDS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081361/65387), here's my solution:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

def response(request, template=None, vars={}):
    if template is None:
        view_func = resolve(request.META['REQUEST_URI'])[0]
        app_label = view_func.__module__.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
        view_name = view_func.__name__
        template = '%s.html' % os.path.join(app_label, view_name)
    return render_to_response(template, vars, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now you can just call `return response(request)` at the end of your view funcs and it will automatically load up `app/view.html` as the template and pass in the request context.

Comment: given you already have the request you can simply do "request.resolver_match" instead of calling resolve