# How to get model name used in view from a Django request object in middleware?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, middleware

I have an a django app for which I am writing middleware for. In the middleware, I have `process_exception` function where I have a the `request` object which is a `WSGI Request` object.

I want to get the view that the request has passed through. How can I do that?

If I try `request.view`, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'view'
```

I would further like to get model, serializer being used in that view but ofcourse I can do that using `getattr` easily once I get the view.

Comment: Possibly useful info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491605/how-to-get-the-current-url-name-using-django

Comment: Possibly useful info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989848/django-get-name-of-current-view-as-a-string

Comment: Possibly useful info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081327/get-view-function-from-request-uri/3081361

Answer (score 1):

Although the request does not have an attribute indicating it's view you can get that as follows:

```
from django.urls import resolve

class MyMiddleware:
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        # code
        resolver_match = resolve(request.path_info)
        view_function = resolver_match.func # matching view function
        url_name = resolver_match.url_name # name of the matching url
        # code
```

Referred from the documentation [resolve](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve), [ResolverMatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch), [attributes of HttpRequest (path_info)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects)