# Get View associated with a URL

Tags: django, django-views

I'm looking to know the associated class-based view that is associated with a path.

Say I have URL pattern like this :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("hello/<str:name>/", views.HelloView.as_view(), name="hello-page")
]
```

Could I, from a path like "hello/foo/" get back to the HelloView class ?

Ideally I'd like to be able to do it like this :

```py
the_url = "hello/foo/"
url_associated_view = get_view_class_from_path(the_url)
print(url_associated_view)
>> HelloView
```

It's different from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081327/get-view-function-from-request-uri) because the suggested answer only gives me the as_view function as a value, while I'm trying to get the HelloView class as return value.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat No it doesn't, because the output of this gives me the function "as_view" as a result, which is not what I'm looking for. I can't get to trace back to the class from there.

Comment: The function returned by the `as_view` method has a `view_class` attribute to it. So you can simply say `func.view_class` and get the class.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It worked like a charm, I could access the `.model` attribute of the `.view_class`, thanks a lot !